# How to add jar to classPatch during runtime to get compiled class package imports resolved

Tags: java

I've made a simple Java compiler tool, which compiles class passed as String, if compilation fails result is retuned as String (OK or compilation error). It works with a class which imports only packages included in jre. When class imports package which is not included in classPatch compilation error occurs - as espected for now. The problem is that when I'm checking a class which imprts external package I want to load this package during runtime, so compiler will be able to resolve imports. I was checking all possible solutions, including system classLoaders, context classloaders, all possible tools like [JCL classloader](https://github.com/kamranzafar/JCL) (except OSGI container, which I don't want to use), but nothing seems to work like I need. It all just returns class object, where you can get it's instance and invoke method. That's not what I need. Here's my compiler code:

```
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
/**
 * Plugins compiler - checks if Java class is correct. If compilation is correct it returns "OK", otherwise it returns compiler error.
 */
public class PluginsCompiler
{

    public static final File TEMP_DIR = new File("C://YourDir//");

    public String compile(String javaSource) throws IOException
    {
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

        /*
         * We create our own OutputStream, which simply writes error into String
         */
        OutputStream output = new OutputStream()
        {
            private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException
            {
                this.sb.append((char) b);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString()
            {
                return this.sb.toString();
            }
        };

        /*
         * We need to write file temporary before compiling it
         */
        String classNameWithPath =
                        TEMP_DIR.getAbsolutePath().toString() + "\\" + this.getClassName(javaSource)
                                        + ".java";
        File file = new File(classNameWithPath);

       /*
        * if file doesn't exists, then we create it
        */
        if (!file.exists())
        {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        try
        {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(javaSource);
            bw.close();
            compiler.run(null, null, output, classNameWithPath);
        }
        finally
        {
            for (File f : TEMP_DIR.listFiles())
            {
                f.delete();
            }
        }
        return output.toString().length() == 0 ? "OK" : output.toString();
    }

    private String getClassName(String classSource)
    {
        Pattern patter = Pattern.compile("(class\\s)(\\w+)(\\s|\\\\n|\\{)");
        Matcher matcher = patter.matcher(classSource);
        String className = "";

        if (matcher.find())
        {
            className = matcher.group(2);
        }

        return className;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String testSource = "package com.test;\n"
                        + "import java.io.IOException;\n"
                        + "public class ExternaPlugin\n"
                        + "{\n"
                        + "    public void foo(String title, String message) throws IOException\n"
                        + "    {\n"
                        + "        System.out.println(title + \" \" + message);\n"
                        + "    }\n"
                        + "}\n";

        PluginsCompiler compiler = new PluginsCompiler();
        System.out.println(compiler.compile(testSource));
    }
}
```

For example if test class would look like this:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;   
import org.junit.Test;

public class MyTests{

  @Test
  public void multiplicationOfZeroIntegersShouldReturnZero() {

    // assert statements
    assertEquals("10 x 0 must be 0", 0, 10 * 0);

  }
}
```

Compilation will fail because of not resolved imports. So I want to load package junit-4.12.jar so compiler will resolve this package. Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: From where do you would know before compiling which classes/jars are needed?

Comment: I will know a patch to jar before compiling. I just want to make a field to put the code and browse button to jar, so I will have both a jar and patch to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an amended classpath to the compiler like shown in the snippet.

```
File[] files = new File[]{new File("/path/to/source/MyTests.java")};

JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

String classPath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
String testpath = classPath + ";/path/to/lib/junit-4.10.jar";

List<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
options.addAll(Arrays.asList("-classpath", testpath));

try (StandardJavaFileManager filemanager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(
        null, null, null)) {
    Iterable fileObjects = filemanager.getJavaFileObjects(files);
    JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(
            null, null, null, options, null, fileObjects);
    task.call();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I see it adds a jar to classPatch. It still doesn't work, but showed me direction to find out how to do it.

Comment: @RichardK Where is your problem? The snippet in my answer is a working example. And your example source file get compiled.

Comment: I have added it like this: http://pastebin.com/DbvHbnD1 and it gives: C:\Temp\Compiler\MyTests.java:1: error: package org.junit does not exist
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;    This is a valid patch to jar.
                       ^

Comment: @RichardK `task.call()` actually does the compilation so remove your additional line `compiler.run(null, null, output, classNameWithPath)`. This is the one which is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible. Java compiler does need to know the return type of methods AND types of method parameters.